# QtCreator shows 'Build Problems' when instantiating Object in property-assignment

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to have an `QtObject` accessible through a property of another `QtObject`.
In this concrete case, a `QtObject` serves as a model for various `Items`.

TestObj.qml

```
QtObject {
    id: root
    property real position: 0
    readonly property NumberAnimation animation: NumberAnimation { // <-*1
        target: root
        property: 'position' //<-*2
        from: 0
        to: 1
        duration: 10000 * (1 - position)
        onRunningChanged: console.log('running', running)
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    width: 700
    height: 700
    visible: true

    Button {
        x: 600 * model.position
        y: 400 * model.position
        onClicked: model.animation.running = true
    }

    TestObj {
        id: model
    }
}
```

It runs flawless, as expected. However the QtCreator finds some "Build Problems" at the two marked lines (`<-*`) in `TestObj.qml`.

*1: It expects the token: ','
 *2: It expects the token: '}'

What's up with the QtCreator (4.0.2, Windows)? *Is it right or wrong?*
When I remove the `readonly`, the problems disappear, but I want it to be readonly.

For me it would be sufficient, to have the `running`-property exposed, but as QtObjects can't have (visual) children for it has no default property, I can't see any other way to do this.

Comment: Which version of Creator? I don't see it with 4.1.0.

Comment: Oh yeah. You are right: It is 4.0.2 on Windows. So it seems like a bug, that has been fixed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this with Creator 4.1.0, so it could be that it is a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: I'll try it out later. Thank you for this hint!